# " DMAKE WARNING " ora2pg installation

Tags: citrix, ora2pg

I'm trying to install ora2pg tool in my virtual machine on citrix xenserver , and I keep getting this error , any idea on how to fix the issue ? thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nipW.png)

Comment: That is a WARNING, not an ERROR

Comment: I have to do a > dmake install to install the DBI , but apparently this command is not working !

Answer (score 1):

i test with gmake and it works

```
PS C:\Utilitaires\ora2pg-20.0> gmake
cp lib/Ora2Pg/MySQL.pm blib\lib\Ora2Pg\MySQL.pm
cp lib/Ora2Pg/PLSQL.pm blib\lib\Ora2Pg\PLSQL.pm
cp lib/Ora2Pg.pm blib\lib\Ora2Pg.pm
cp lib/Ora2Pg/GEOM.pm blib\lib\Ora2Pg\GEOM.pm
"C:\Utilitaires\programs\strawberryperl\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e cp -- scripts/ora2pg blib\script\ora2pg
pl2bat.bat blib\script\ora2pg
"C:\Utilitaires\programs\strawberryperl\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e cp -- scripts/ora2pg_scanner blib\script\ora2pg_scanner
pl2bat.bat blib\script\ora2pg_scanner
PS C:\Utilitaires\ora2pg-20.0> gmake install
Installing C:\UTILIT~1\programs\STRAWB~1\perl\site\lib\Ora2Pg.pm
Installing C:\UTILIT~1\programs\STRAWB~1\perl\site\lib\Ora2Pg\GEOM.pm
Installing C:\UTILIT~1\programs\STRAWB~1\perl\site\lib\Ora2Pg\MySQL.pm
Installing C:\UTILIT~1\programs\STRAWB~1\perl\site\lib\Ora2Pg\PLSQL.pm
Installing C:\UTILIT~1\programs\STRAWB~1\perl\site\bin\ora2pg
Installing C:\UTILIT~1\programs\STRAWB~1\perl\site\bin\ora2pg.bat
Installing C:\UTILIT~1\programs\STRAWB~1\perl\site\bin\ora2pg_scanner
Installing C:\UTILIT~1\programs\STRAWB~1\perl\site\bin\ora2pg_scanner.bat
"Installing default configuration file (ora2pg_dist.conf) to C:\ora2pg"
Appending installation info to C:\UTILIT~1\programs\STRAWB~1\perl\lib/perllocal.pod
```